# Why does my Neural Network always predict 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to classify Drowsy and non drowsy faces using CNN. I have total 28608 images(which i created by augmenting). I use 21456 images for training, 7152 for testing and 2000 for validation. I am getting an *accuracy:0.93 and loss:0.17*

But still when I try to predict few images randomly from test data it always gives a 0.

Can someone please help me with this?

```
# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import random
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

print(tf.__version__)

DATADIR ="D:\\s1\\DATA"

CATEGORIES = ["D", "ND"]
IMG_SIZE = 50

training_data = []
#############################################################  0=Drowsy 1=NonDrowsy
def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:  # do D and ND

        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to D and ND
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  # get the classification  (0 or a 1). 0=D 1=ND

        for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image per D and ND
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,0)  # convert to array
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])  # add this to  training_data
            except Exception as e:  # in the interest in keeping the output clean...
                pass

create_training_data()

random.shuffle(training_data)

x=[]
y=[]

for features,label in training_data:
    x.append(features)
    y.append(label)

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)


####################################################################

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)


####################################

X_train = X_train / 255.0
X_test = X_test / 255.0


X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)


model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

#Validation set
x_val = X_train[:2000]
partial_x_train = X_train[2000:]

y_val = y_train[:2000]
partial_y_train = y_train[2000:]

history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=5,batch_size=100, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),verbose=1)
###########
results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(results)
################


for i in range(6):
    print(i)
    img1 = X_test[i]
    print(img1.shape)
    img1 = (np.expand_dims(img1,0))
    print(img1.shape)

    print('actual label')
    print(y_test[i])


    predictions_single = model.predict(img1)
    print('predicted label')

    print(predictions_single)
    print(np.argmax(predictions_single[0]))
    print('########################################')
    print('########################################')
```

Comment: I would find it much easier if you simplified the included source code. You should at least remove the commented code if it is not related to the problem. It would be also helpful to provide the exact output of each print command.
I can only guess at the moment, but it seems that you are applying `argmax` on an object that is either scalar or 1-dimensional array. In such case you get 0 because the largest (and only) number is on the 0th index.

Comment: Another basic question: How many of your training samples are showing drowsy/non-drowsy faces? did you do any analysis on your data split beforehand? If you have an imbalanced dataset, that could be the reason, too...

Comment: @dennlinger I have equal amount of drowsy and non drowsy images for training

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to keep the list `training_data` completely global and the function `create_training_data()` expected to update it from the inside, try creating it wholly in the function and returning it:

```
#############################################################  0=Drowsy 1=NonDrowsy
def create_training_data():

    training_data = []

    for category in CATEGORIES:  # do D and ND
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to D and ND
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  # get the classification  (0 or a 1). 0=D 1=ND
        for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image per D and ND
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,0)  # convert to array
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])  # add this to  training_data
            except Exception as e:  # in the interest in keeping the output clean...
                pass

    return training_data


training_data = create_training_data()
```

You may also want to consider passing the other variables into your function as parameters, to avoid similar problems.